# Reference in Spanish and English language in BibTeX

Tags: bibtex, citing, babel, spanish

I'm typing my thesis and I'm using LaTeX for it. I've found one problem in my references. I'm using two language for my references: Spanish and English, but for the last language ,  I can't change the word "En" instead "In".

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[left=4cm,right=4cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage[english,main=spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{filecontents}

 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

 \begin{filecontents*}{bib2.bib}
 @InProceedings{vallejo:book2014,
 crossref = {book2014},
 author = {Malaspina, U.  and Vallejo, E.},
 title = {Creaci\'on de {P}roblemas en la {D}ocencia e {I}nvestigaci\'on.},
 pages = {7--54},
 language = {Spanish}
  }
  \end{filecontents*}
  \begin{filecontents*}{crossref2.bib}
  @book{book2014,
  booktitle =  {Reflexiones y {P}ropuestas en {E}ducaci\'on {M}atem\'atica},
  title =     {Reflexiones y {P}ropuestas en {E}ducaci\'on {M}atem\'atica},
  year =      2014,
  address =      {Lima, Per\'u},
  publisher =    {Editorial {M}oshera {S}.{R}.{L}.},
   language = {Spanish}
   }
  \end{filecontents*}
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{filecontents*}{bib3.bib}
 @InProceedings{killpatrick2014:handbook2014,
 crossref = {handbook2014},
 author = {Kilpatrick, Jeremy},
 title = {History of Research in Mathematics Education},
 pages = {267--272},
 language = {English},
  }
  \end{filecontents*}
 \begin{filecontents*}{crossref3.bib}
 @book{handbook2014,
 booktitle =  {Encyclopedia of {M}athematics {E}ducation},
 title =     {Encyclopedia of {M}athematics {E}ducation},
 year =      2014,
 publisher = {Springer Netherlands},
 editor = {Lerman, Stephen},
 language = {English},
  }
 \end{filecontents*}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand{\BBAA}{\&}  % between authors in parenthetical cites and ref. list
 \renewcommand{\BBAB}{\&}  % between authors in in-text citation
 \renewcommand{\BAnd}{\&}  % for ``Ed. \& Trans.'' in ref. list
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

 Mis referencias son \cite{killpatrick2014:handbook2014} y  \cite{vallejo:book2014}

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
 \bibliography{bib2,crossref2,bib3,crossref3}


  \end{document}
```

Here is my result:

[image: Here is my result]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I believe you should use the same language (viz., Spanish) for the particles ("y", "en", etc) for *all* entries. Otherwise, for the sake of consistency, you'll need to provide French particles for French-language entries, German particles for German-language entries, Italian particles for Italian-language entries, etc., etc. Since the main document is in Spanish, that's the language that should govern the syntactic structure of the bibliographic entries.